# Trying to send email with phpmailer and g-suite

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Trying to send email with phpmailer and g-suite

I'm trying to send an email with PHPmailer using g-suite account but i'm not able to...

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  
try {

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'email@email.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('email@email.com', 'email');
$mail->addAddress('email@email.com');
$mail->addAddress('email@email.com');


//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'test';
$mail->Body = 'test';


$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Also in g-suit i change this one:
[image]

This is the error i'm getting:

```
    2019-02-23 02:11:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2019-02-23 02:11:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-02-23 02:11:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2019-02-23 02:11:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2019-02-23 02:11:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2019-02-23 02:11:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2019-02-23 02:11:08 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials n16sm4194375wmk.45 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2019-02-23 02:11:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I'm trying to run this one on a xampp sever, i also trying it to run on my hosting with ssl and still not working... any idea?

Comment: ok, but in gaagle, did the `user` enable the use of less secure apps, now that you have allowed it ?

Comment: did you solve it? if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'tsl' to 'tls'.

That's the only mistake I am seeing.

Comment: I just modified on the question because it was my fault on paste here on stack, on my code is TLS, so the error is the same i'm showing u

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've solved by using not my own password in PHPMailer, but created a APP password from google. It's a 16-character long random string, which can be generated in your Google account.

Go to: myaccount.google.com
Go to: Security
Click on: App-passwords (Or something like that)
Generate your app password and copy that into your PHPMailer file.